# Combining use of `choices` and `action='extend'` in argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I ran into a corner case with `choice` in `argparse`, when used in conjunction with `action='extend'`, introduced in python 3.8:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser('test')
parser.add_argument('-x', '--x', action='extend', choices=list('XYZ'), type=list)
parser.parse_args(['-x', 'XXYYZZ'])
```

My expectation (perhaps desire) is that each element of `['X', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Z', 'Z']` get checked (successfully) against `choices`. Instead, the following error message is printed:

```
usage: test [-h] [-x {X,Y,Z}]
test: error: argument -x/--x: invalid choice: ['X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Z', 'Z'] (choose from 'X', 'Y', 'Z')
```

Is there a way to apply `choices` to each element of an iterable with `action='extend'` instead of the entire thing? FWIW, this works fine if I allow multiple instances of `-x` and use `action='append'` instead...

Answer (score 1):

Convert type to `str` and pass values(`"X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Z", "Z"`) to the argument instead of a single combined string `"XXYYZZ"`

The combination of `nargs="+"` and `action="extend"` tells the parser to accept the 1 or more values provided for the `-x` argument as a list and extend the list with those values.

This works,

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('test')
parser.add_argument("-x", "--x", action="extend", nargs="+", type=str, choices=list('XYZ'))
parser.parse_args(["-x", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Z", "Z"])
# parser.parse_args(["-x"] + list("XXYYZZ"))
```

---

**Output:**

```
Namespace(x=['X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Z', 'Z'])
```

Comment: More of a workaround than a solution, but still food for thought. My real usecase is a much more complex parsing operation than just splitting a string.

Comment: The type will already be `str` by default. What's doing the work here is separating the arguments and using `nargs='+'`.

Answer (score 0):

For each argument, it is passed though `type` function, and the result is tested against `choices`.

You provide one argument, 'XXXYZ', Your type, `list` converts it to a list, and it's that whole list that's tested.

I don't think 'extend' is the problem here, the default 'store' behaves the same. It's your use of `type=list` that's unusual. –

I wasn't involved in adding 'extend' to `argparse`, but I think it's just like 'append', except in how the value list is added to the preexisting list in the namespace.  Test them without 'choices' and that list type.

In the argparse.py source cide, ifps the `_get_values` function, for `nargs in [None]` case and the sequence of

```
_get_value
_check_value
```

that's relevant.

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/argparse.py

### edit

you could write a custom `type` function that expands the string with list, and does its own test of the elements.

### again

I haven't looked at the use of `list` type before.  Let's see what happens (without the choices testing).

```
In [137]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [138]: parser.add_argument('--foo', type=list);
In [140]: parser.parse_args('--foo XXYYZ'.split())
Out[140]: Namespace(foo=['X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Z'])
```

So with the default Action class, we do get a list of characters, just as `list()` does.

With `append`, we get a list within a list:

```
In [141]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [142]: parser.add_argument('--foo', type=list, action='append');
In [143]: parser.parse_args('--foo XXYYZ'.split())
Out[143]: Namespace(foo=[['X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Z']])
```

With extend it looks just like the default case:

```
In [144]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [145]: parser.add_argument('--foo', type=list, action='extend');
In [146]: parser.parse_args('--foo XXYYZ'.split())
Out[146]: Namespace(foo=['X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Z'])
```

But the difference from the default is more apparent if we repeat the option:

```
In [147]: parser.parse_args('--foo XXYYZ --foo ABC'.split())
Out[147]: Namespace(foo=['X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'C'])
In [148]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [149]: parser.add_argument('--foo', type=list, action='append');
In [150]: parser.parse_args('--foo XXYYZ --foo ABC'.split())
Out[150]: Namespace(foo=[['X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Z'], ['A', 'B', 'C']])
```

`extend` keeps them in a flat list, `append` is nested.  Avoiding this nesting was the main reason `extend` was added.

Your use of `list` is functionally a lot like using `nargs='*'` as suggested in the other answer.  Except the user has to split the string first.

In other SO we've suggested, as altenatives to `choices`, to put the testing in the `type` function, or in the custom Action `__call__`.  But if the testing involves other arguments, it may be easier to wait until after parsing, when all argument values are available.

Comment: Your edit is probably what I was looking for.

Comment: More to the point, I think I will want a custom action that's based on `_ExtendAction` but does option checking a bit differently

Comment: Typically the Action subclasses just take care of storing the values in the namespace, but it certainly could do other manipulations to the values.  Error handling might be different - just raising an ArgumentError,  `type` handling can catch value/time/argumentType errors.

Comment: Aside from a custom `type`, this could probably also be handled with a custom `action`.